# Error after working for a while in a Python code for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape out all mobile data from the flipkart site
using python 2.7 (through idle)  and beautiful soup.
Below is my code, In 1st part of my code, i am getting all the  individual links of all samsung mobiles and in the **2nd part** i am scraping all the mobile specification(td element) from those respective pages.
But after few mobiles, i get the following error msg that

```
 ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\data base python\collectinghrefsamasungstack.py", line 16, in <module>
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)  #//.request is in 3.0x
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

my code

```
    import urllib
    import re  
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    #part1
    url="http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io"

    regex = '<a class="fk-display-block" data-tracking-id="prd_title" href=(.+?)title'  # it will find the title
    pattern=re.compile(regex)

    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)

    htmltext= htmlfile.read()
    docSoup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    abc=docSoup.findAll('a')
    c=str(abc)

    count=0
    #------part 2     it goes to each link and gathers the mobile specificattions
    title=re.findall(pattern,c)

    temp=1
    file2=open('c:/Python27/samsung.txt','w')

    for i in title:
        print i
        file2.write(i)
        file2.write("\n")
        count=count+1
        print "\n1\n"
        #print i
        if temp>0 :
            mob_url='http://www.flipkart.com'+i[1:len(i)-2]
            htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(mob_url)
            htmltext= htmlfile.read()
            # htmltext
            docSoup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

            abc=docSoup.find_all('td')
            file=open('c:/Python27/prut2'+str(count)+'.txt','w')
            mod=0
            count=count+1
            pr=-1
            for j in abc:
                if j.text == 'Brand':
                    pr=3

                if mod ==1:
                    file2.write((j).text)
                    file2.write("\n")
                    mod=0
                if j.text == 'Model ID':
                    mod=1
                #sprint j.text

                if pr>0 :
                    file.write(j.text)
                    file.write('\n')

                file.close
        else :
            temp=temp+1



    print count
    file2.close
```

I tried disabling the antivirus and the net connection which i am using is quite stable only, but still I am getting the error so is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: You may possible be hitting some throttling limit and ignored... You can test that by putting a delay between your requests

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you open too many connections.

add `htmlfile.close()` after `htmltext= htmlfile.read()`.